# Detect outliers or noise data in each group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, outliers, dbscan

I'm working for a data which have 3 columns: `type`, `x`, `y`, let's say `x` and `y` are correlated and they not normalizedly distributed, I want groupby `type` and filter `outliers` or `noise` data points in `x` and `y`. Could someone recommend me statitics or machine learning methods to filter outliers or noise data? How can I do that in Python?

I'm considering to use `DBSCAN` from `scikit-learn`, is it appropriate method ?

Type1:
[image: type1]
Type2:
[image]
Type3:
[image]

```
df1 = df.loc[df['type'] == '3']

data= df1[["x", "y"]]
data.plot.scatter(x = "x", y = "y")

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
outlier_detection = DBSCAN(
  eps = 0.5,
  metric="euclidean",
  min_samples = 3,
  n_jobs = -1)
clusters = outlier_detection.fit_predict(data)

from matplotlib import cm
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Accent')
data.plot.scatter(
  x = "iSearchCount",
  y = "iGuaPaiCount",
  c = clusters,
  cmap = cmap,
  colorbar = False
)
```

[image]

Comment: [`scipy.stats.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) worked for me

Comment: Is that robust?

Comment: Certainly *much* more robust than clustering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of data and outliers I would recommend a statistical approach. The SPE/DmodX (distance to model) or  Hotelling T2 test may help you here. I do not see the data for the 3 types but I generated some.

These methods are available in the `pca` library. With the `n_std` you can adjust the ellipse "width".

```
pip install pca

import pca
results = pca.spe_dmodx(X, n_std=3, showfig=True)

# If you want to test the Hotelling T2 test.
# results1 = pca.hotellingsT2(X, alpha=0.001)
```

[image: example results]

`results` is a dictionary and contains the labels of the outliers.

Answer (score 2):

After some feature engineering techniques you could consider using OneClassSVM estimator from Sklearn library.

https://justanoderbit.com/outlier-detection/one-class-svm/ describes how to use it for outlier detection.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you don't get good results if you don't care about the parameters. Just look at your plot. The scale is huge - your epsilon is tiny! Seems like your data may be integers, so no points except duplicates will ever have a distance of less than 0.5...
Hence all data is considered noise.

Before using a method, make sure you've understood how it works and what parameters you need to set.

I'd also log transform the data first. Working with some simple thresholds may be enough. Don:t overdo things with clustering when your data is unimodal.

Comment: Thanks, I remove upper data with threshould `quantile(0.9998)`, it seems `log transformation` or not `x` and `y` didn't change the result.

Comment: Obviously log does not affect the quantiles. But the plot may be more helpful.

Comment: Maybe i should try with log transformation and then use IQR or z score, does that make sense?

Comment: From the plots above, zscore most likely is better after log than before. But if you have 0 counts, you may also need to consider log1p or sqrt or box-cox.